# Succinct, shorthand, (possibly) Latin word similar to "ala"

Tags: american-english, latin

I'm trying to find the world that one would use to denote a connection to a person's idea.  I'm writing a sentence where I want to make a simple connection to Jonathan Edwards' "Sinners in the hands of an angry God".  What I have is

`it is God holding us over the flames, ala Jonathan Edwards`

but I would like to find a better word than `ala` for making the connective idea.

Answer (score 2):

I presume that your *ala* is a nonstandard spelling of [*à la*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/a-la), a somewhat informal phrase taken directly from the French with the same meaning: ‘in the same style, manner, sense of.’ While one might find the expression written with an unaccented a, writing it together is a bit beyond the pale.

I would write:

> It is God holding us over the flames, in the Jonathan Edward sense.

Or if the name or phrase makes an attributive use unwieldy:

> While for many situations the conventional assumptions usually employed in economic analyses as, for example, strong rationality *[in the sense of](https://books.google.de/books?id=J-7whzmqdqoC&pg=PP7&dq=%22in%20the%20sense%20of%20John%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwii-ffow9ThAhXuxaYKHaZwApsQ6AEIMzAD)* JOHN VON NEUMANN and OSKAR MORGENSTERN (1948), are not appropriate or even rejected, the basic structure of the model remains the same. — Gebhard Kirchgässer, *Homo Œconomicus*, 2008.

Comment: Thanks.  The word I have in mind is one that I think is Latin but would replace `a la`.  When I search for it what Google wants to tell me is that the Latin word for `a la` means wing, which is most definitely not what I'm after. Something like 'viz' or 'et al', or something along those lines.

Or maybe `viz` is what I'm thinking of...